# JavaScript Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of null

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2016

I am checking the phoneNumber.length in my CRM form. So far I got the check between 8-15 character = acceptable to work. When I try to stack an 'if' to check for zero characters I get:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of null at checkPhoneNumber**

```
function checkPhoneNumber(executioncontext) {
    var phoneNumber;
    phoneNumber = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("telephone1").getValue();

    if (phoneNumber == null) {
        Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification("Phonenumber can't be empty", "WARNING", "telephone1nc1");
        Xrm.Page.getControl("telephone1").setFocus(true);
        executioncontext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
    } else {
        Xrm.Page.ui.clearFormNotification("telephone1nc1");
        //Insert 8-15 characters
        if (phoneNumber != null) {

            if (phoneNumber.length < 8 || phoneNumber.length > 15) {
                Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification("Phonenumber must be between 8-15 chars..", "ERROR", "telephoneerror1");
                Xrm.Page.getControl("telephone1").setFocus(true);
            } else {
                if (phoneNumber == null) {
                    Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification("Telefonnummret får inte vara tomt", "WARNING", "telephone1nc1");
                    Xrm.Page.getControl("telephone1").setFocus(true);
                    //executioncontext.getEventArgs().preventDefault(); //vid 0 bombar scriptet
                } else {

                    Xrm.Page.ui.clearFormNotification("telephone1nc1");
                }
                Xrm.Page.ui.clearFormNotification("telephoneerror1");

            }
            /*var regex = /^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$/;

            if (regex.test(executionObj)) {
                // Valid international phone number
            } else {
                // Invalid international phone number */
        }
    }
}
```

Once I get that sorted out I will start working on the code to check for international format and inserting the country code based on country of the entity. Hence the commented **var regex**.

Comment: `executioncontext.getEventArgs()` returns null, which causes your error. 
As to why is that, we would need more context on the `executioncontext` variable.

Comment: Ah, yes. It is to clear the warning message `Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification("Telefonnummret får inte vara tomt", "WARNING", "telephone1nc1");`
Once a value is typed in telephone1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure `executioncontext.getEventArgs()` is not null.

Easiest way to do this in a single line:

```
executioncontext.getEventArgs() && executioncontext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

`executionContext.getEventArgs()` for Dynamics CRM is only relevant for save-events:

> [This method returns null for any event other than the Save event.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328130.aspx#Anchor_3)

It would appear that your code is not (only) running OnSave.

With that being said, the normal way of forcing users to fill out fields in Dynamics CRM is to make them Business Required (i.e. the fields get red asterisks, and users cannot save the form without filling the fields) - not to manually make form notifications.